# Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, association

Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus? My Stack Overflow account has about 1300 points, and I created accounts on all the other sites. My Meta Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow accounts got a 100 reputation point bonus, but my Super User and Server Fault accounts didn't get bonuses. Is this correct?

I'm asking because of the Meta Stack Overflow question *[On a new SE site, how do the first users get reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/on-a-new-stackoverflow-type-site-how-do-the-first-users-get-experience)* that I asked.

Comment: Fixing - if any account has the required rep, the bonus will be awarded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be getting a 100 point bonus on all sites.

It has been noted that you must link all the accounts from a site that has more than 200 rep, otherwise the bonus will not be applied.

In your case you should email team@stackoverflow.com and see if they can't help hook you up.

Comment: That would explain it. It shouldn't matter which account you use, as long as one of them is 200+. Especially since most users will be doing the linking from the site they just signed up for.

Comment: When I registered with SU I linked my accounts from there and got the bonus. Did I just get lucky?

Comment: I've encountered this as well -- I associated my new meta account with a just-created SF account rather than SO. Clearing all associations and associating with the highest-rep site gave me the +100 bonus.

Answer (score 7):

Clearing and re-associating gets you the bonus, but you should do it over a few days because of the 200 rep/day limit.