# Linked account didn't get 100 rep points

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association, association-bonus

I linked this recently (36 days ago)

https://superuser.com/users/34077/andy-es-head

According to Jarrod's comment on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus), linked accounts should get 100 rep if any of the others have more than 200.  Looks like I hit a bug or something, I got the 100 rep points on meta and SF.

Not that I'm bothered about the rep, but I feel it is my duty to report such issues immediately should I encounter one. **salutes**

---

[Daniel's answer][2] is a suitable workaround.  I can't help wondering if I should have left it as is until the bug had been investigated, though.

---

*ire_and_curses* pointed out that this bug is probably no longer relevant due to the [auto-linking feature introduced today](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove and relink, that worked for me when it happened to me.

edit:  To be clear, that doesn't make it not a bug, I just happened to notice a workaround that worked for me.

Comment: I could do that.  I only have 11 rep and 2 easy-to-get bronze badges so I'm not losing out on anything.

Comment: @Andy: No, no. He means to remove the *association*, and try re-linking.

Comment: @Jon Siegel: lol I see now *facepalm*. Yes, it worked.

Comment: You shouldn't need to relink anymore. Unlink, then just log in with the same OpenID. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/

Comment: hmm... seems like this thread is no longer relevant.

Comment: @ire I think the new auto-association probably works only once. Otherwise, manually unlinking your accounts (should you actively wish them to be dissociated) wouldn't be effective for very long.

Comment: When I've got 200 rep in SO, I've just pressed the `Copy Stack Overflow profile to all related accounts` in my profile's `accounts` tab, and I've got +100 rep on SO and other sites. :)

Answer (score 4):

you WILL get the +100 if you have +200 in the network *AT THE TIME OF ASSOCIATION*.

But, there's no magical "oh, you passed +200, so we're going to give you +100 now" process running in the background.

So, if you pass the +200 mark later you need to unassociate and re-associate to get the +100 bonus.

Comment: T_T I've never seen you write so many caps, my friend. >_o

Comment: Just to clarify, I only registered on SU 36 days ago, after registering and linking on the other sites (which worked fine).  But I kind of sense your answer is directed towards the auto-association thing anyhow.