# No bonus points on linking the accounts

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association

I am not getting any bonus points. I checked all the related questions to this but not getting any solutions.
can anybody tell me the exact procedure. I am using all these sites randomly but using stackoverflow on regular basics and havin more than 700 points there. How i can get these 100 bonus points

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked account didn't get 100 rep points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50503/linked-account-didnt-get-100-rep-points)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of about 6-8 months ago, you will get the +100 bonus network wide as soon as you pass +200 rep on any Stack Exchange network site.

Comment: I think it checks for 200 reputation now, I've just crossed 200 and all my other accounts are awarded with 100 extra

Comment: thanks @neerad I updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

The same question was asked here 41 mins before yours: [Linked account didn't get 100 rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50503/linked-account-didnt-get-100-rep-points)

The suggested solution to unlink the account and relink it again did work. Give it a try.