# Manual rep recalc (new user) - lost 500 points - nothing in audit re associated accounts?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

Hi all - I just did a "self instigated" rep recalc (on SO) and lost 500 points.

I only joined 7 months ago - i.e. wasn't here for the March recalc.

It looks to me from the audit output text that there is no indication of any bonus points awarded for associating other stack exchange accounts.

Could this be a bug?

Comment: for me the first line on /reputation says *bonuses (100)* which is the association bonus

Comment: Mine also says 100 - but, for example, I joined two stack exchange sites today and was awarded 100 points for each. Before the recalc I had managed to reach 440 points for the day (240 normal points, 100 points each for joining two additional sites). Now I've lost that 200 plus earlier ones as well (I have a total of 6 associated accounts). I did try de-linking are re-linking but it had no effect.

Comment: *awarded 100 points for each* I guess that's an error: [New Automatic Account Association](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/) claims *"Grant you a +100 reputation bonus on the current site, as long as you have at least +200 reputation on any site in our network. So you’re not treated like a newbie on every new site we launch."* So, at most +100 per site? That should still show in the overview though.

Comment: @Arjan - thanks...I guess that explains it, kinda.

Comment: The bug was that the +100 was awarded more than once...the recalc is correct.  It should be awarded only the first time per site.

Comment: @Nick - and only on your score for the newly joined site, yes? It was a bit odd to have all those points go to SO - i.e. why not other sites?

Comment: But then, it still should show you that +100 bonus on the 2nd line! (Once on SO, and once on each newly joined site.)

Comment: See also [Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus) (Which is a bit old though.)

Comment: @sje397 - Correct, that's where the points should go, to the site you don't already have them on, e.g. if I login to a new SE site, I should get +100 there on association.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding account association: As others have said already, you only ever get 100 rep on each site for associating, no matter how many sites you associated with.

Regarding the reputation loss: I looked at your profile (moderators can see deleted posts in user profiles); if I haven't miscounted, you have a total score of 37 on deleted answers (most of them deleted by yourself). This accounts for at least 370 reputation already; possibly more if some of these posts also had downvotes.

When a post is deleted, the loss of these upvotes isn't immediately reflected in the poster's reputation, so this is the biggest part of those 500 rep you lost.

Comment: How quickly is it reflected? Can you see my score yesterday vs before the recalc today vs after? I'm (99%) sure I was 88xx points yesterday, and 925x points before the recalc.

Comment: Hm...maybe 99% is an overestimate...I'm starting to doubt my memory, and think perhaps I just lost a day somewhere (maybe some evil addictive internet site stole it). Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @sje397: It's never reflected until a rep recalc, so your memory can be correct -- as I said, at least 370 are accounted for (plus 8 for each downvote any of those answers had). The rest (if any) is probably upvotes from users who where subsequently deleted.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a lot of points, but if you are active, you will collect some of these ghost points.

You probably had a fan or some answers on deleted questions.

**Edit**
We got this kind of questions a lot. Maybe there should be some kind of report or at least a notice in the user activity. Like:

```
Reputation recalc, 210 ghost points removed.
```

Comment: But - in the audit text, there is no '+100 for associated account' - and the audit numbers add up. I used to have points for having added those other accounts.

Comment: @sje397, if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation you get the full report. The numbers must add to the final total.  If that isn't the case, you can add the differences.

Comment: @Gamecat - Yes, this is where I went to push the button to instigate a manual recalc. The numbers there do add up - but, there is nothing there about the 500 points I had from associated accounts. That is the question - where have the points from associated accounts gone?

Comment: Also, I [suggest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#71678) to add a hint (or a real button!) to first save the current reputation overview before clicking the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button? I guess folks could then figure out what changed themselves, using the previous and new overview. (Or: *is* the overview always the current overview? So one would know IN ADVANCE what would be the result?)

Comment: @Arjan - that's a really good idea.

Comment: Ah, @sje397, my bad: the report IS the actual state. Mine said `total rep 4081` while the header showed `4,360`. After clicking the button the report did not change, but the header did. (The report does show `bonuses (100)` though.)

Comment: Eeek sorry @Arjan, cost you 300 points...

Comment: @sje397, I really couldn't care less, so no worries!