# Error calculating answer points?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529623/are-these-two-statement-the-same-in-actionscript-3#4529657) I have 1 upvote and an accepted answer, even-though in my [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502436/lordcover?tab=reputation) I only have 15 for this question? shouldn't it be 25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation tab only lists rep changes within a range of dates, not the cumulative rep for those questions/answers.  Apparently your upvote came on the day that you answered that question (`2010/12/25`).  I can see that on your rep page in the range `2010/12/24`-`2010/12/26`, you had 10 points rep from that answer.  By default, the reputation tab only shows rep changes from within the last month which currently doesn't include that date.  If you increase the range to include `2010/12/25` and the date your answer was accepted (`2011/02/27`), you will see that it will be listed as having 25 rep gained.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: It shows both the (10) and the (15) points, but when it is shown in the reputation page, should it show the rep cumulative or the last rep action? And I didn't know before about the link you provided, Shouldn't there be some kind of (Page: I'm here!)?

Comment: When I click on `Trigger Reputation Recalc` button on the link you have posted my reputation falls by 32 points. Why so?

Comment: @Harry http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72221/manual-rep-recalc-new-user-lost-500-points-nothing-in-audit-re-associated-a

Comment: @Micheal: got it thnx.