# Bonus reputation not received on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Recently, I received 100 rep because one of my accounts hit 200+ reputation. All the accounts received this addition, except Stack Overflow. Why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *did* receive the association bonus. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, which provides a detailed breakdown of your reputation score. See at the top where it says `--bonuses  (100)`?  That's the association bonus that's been granted to you.

Comment: If I got a +100 bonus, why is my rep still 169, before and after the bonus?
-- 2011-07-18 rep +4    = 169       
-- 2011-07-27 rep 0     = 169
Shouldn't the last entry say 100 = 269?

Comment: Look at the rest of your rep report.  You'll see that your rep starts counting from 101, not 1 since the beginning.  The association bonus is just general "on my account", not "on this day".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest emailing team@stackoverflow.com  They're quite responsive and can probably address this quite quickly.

Comment: That answer is ancient; reassociating really shouldn't do anything anymore

Comment: I edited to remove the second suggestion.